# Vue.js app served on nginx, using Axios/Express, loses HTTPS and becomes HTTP after login page

Tags: express, vue.js, nginx, https, axios

My Vue.js app switches from HTTPS to HTTP after the user logs in, and I'm not sure why. The Vue.js front-end is served using nginx, and uses Axios to access an Express back-end API that queries a local MongoDB server for login and a remote SQL Server for data. If someone could provide any guidance, that would be much appreciated, as this is for a work project.

I'm not sure if this could be a clue, but after logging into a session in the app, if I open a new tab and manually enter a URL for a view that doesn't access the Express back-end (https://subdomain.website.com/view_that_doesnt_access_express_api), the site will be secure under HTTPS, but if I do the same with a view that does access the Express back-end (https://subdomain.website.com/view_that_accesses_express_api), the site will be unsecure and the HTTPS in the location bar is shown crossed out in red.

nginx is configured with SSL and redirects 80 to 443 as follows (/etc/nginx/sites-available/project):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.website.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name _;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/my/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/key.rsa;
        root /path/to/my/dist;
        index index.html

        access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
}
```

The Express server is also configured to be HTTPS (app.js) with the same certification files used by nginx:

```
var httpscert = fs.readFile('cert.crt');
var httpskey = fs.readFile('key.rsa);

var options = {
    key: httpskey,
    cert: httpscert
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Express HTTPS running on 3000");
})
```

Axios (Service.js):

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
    loginUser (email, password) {
        return Api().post('login', {
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    }
}
```

Axios (Api.js):

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://192.168.10.117:3000'
    })
}
```

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so please let me know if I'm not asking this question correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> but if I do the same with a view that does access the Express back-end (https://subdomain.website.com/view_that_accesses_express_api), the site will be unsecure and the HTTPS in the location bar is shown crossed out in red.

That does not mean your setup is wrong, it  just means you have on that page an asset that is served via HTTP, instead of HTTPS. And that's why the lock is crossed.

You should inspect your page source and check for any scripts or styles that are loaded via HTTP. Change those to be HTTPS and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Raul.

The secure view that doesn't access the Express API loads exactly the same assets (the content is currently plain text on all the views), so I wonder if it's something I can find in the source.

The views that are loading as HTTP simply get data from the Express API and display them as text.

Comment: Once your page is loaded, do a "view source" to see the source. You can also open up developer tools for any browser and search for any requests made over HTTP. Mixed content can cause more than just the SSL to not work, for example, a script requested over HTTP might not be loaded, so your page won't work. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

Comment: 100% check your console. Check for any messages about mix content there. Especially images. Scripts and links will automatically get blocked, but an image can cause your site to show not secure.

Comment: Thanks Raul, the source is almost identical because it is a single page application. The secure page has nothing but a title. The only difference is that the unsecure page (also basically just a title) is printing data from the Express API as text. The only mention of HTTP in the source is "<meta http-equiv...>" in the <head>.

Comment: Also, there are no messages in console about mixed-content, as specified in the Google example.

Comment: Here's a demo of what i'm saying: https://jsfiddle.net/L50xh2em/. See how the lock does not show HTTPS? On the other hand, https://jsfiddle.net/be60cj1v/ this works becaue of the image is on HTTPS. Is this what are you seeing on your app? Because if not, i totally missed what you're asking, and i'm sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks Raul, no need to apologize- you are not missing what I'm asking. I'm just saying the secure page is literally a blank page with a single title <div>, and the unsecure page is the same, but with the addition of a few lines of text data pulled from the Express data response. So I think something like a hosted image asset is not causing that issue here.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and open your network console and check what requests are being made when you open up that page? I mean, your config seems good to me. The only thing that I can think of is that it's making those requests over HTTP instead of HTTPS, but I see your axios config is set to use https. That's why i'm a bit puzzled right now.

Comment: Thanks Raul. I see two XHR rows showing on the Network tab: **Request 1** URL: https://192.168.10.117:3000/view, Request Method: OPTIONS, Status: 204 No Content **Request 2** URL: https://192.168.10.117:3000/view, Request Method: GET, Status 200 OK. Is there anything specific in the headers you'd like me to look at ? I also just checked the Network console upon login, and it is basically the same. No http mentioned anywhere..

Comment: Was trying to see if those are over HTTP or HTTPs. But if they are HTTPs, then you should be good. I'm not sure what else i would look at without actually seeing the issue happening, as everything else seems good to me

Comment: Would this maybe be related to the cert and key used by my Express server? Currently they are using the same cert and key for 'subdomain.website.com'. Does it have to be a specific cert and key for the localhost?

Comment: It could actually. You're requesting https://192.168.10.117 with a certificate for subdomain.website.com. If 192.168.10.117 is your A record for subdomain.website.com, you could try to change that in axios and see. Might do work indeed

Comment: Thanks. I tried to set Axios baseurl to https ://subdomain.website.com:3000 but it just times out.

Comment: That's weird man. Isn't that your URL as well? So if you hit https://subdomain.website.com and that works, then https://subdomain.website.com:3000 should also work. Make sure port 3000 is fully opened on the server though, maybe it was set only from localhost?